# I can't access most sites using IPv6. Is it an issue with "Level 3" network?

Tags: networking, internet, routing, ipv6, traceroute

Note: I'm not a network expert, and I don't have deep knowledge about IPv6.

Recently, IPv6 connectivity seems not to be working here. (Tested through Firefox)

The funny thing are, when doing a traceroute:

-it seems like EVERY IPv6 site (I've tested around 30 from different locations around the world) goes through Level3 servers/network/routers;

-it seems like IPv6 packets can't pass Level3 servers/network/routers;

-for a same host using IPv4 instead, traffic passes by other networks, like Sprint (**sl-mst30-mia-hu0-5-0-2.sprintlink.net** [**160.81.164.85**]), for example;

See two examples below: (note IPv6 **2001:450:2001:1000:0:67:1716:8158** in the traceroute is from Level 3 network. See [this](https://ipinfo.io/2001:450:2001:1000:0:67:1716:8158) to check it out)

**www.ipv6forum.com**

```
Tracing route to www.ipv6forum.com [2001:a18:1:20::42]
over a maximum of 99 hops:

1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  2604:XX8X:c98e:6f11:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX
2     2 ms     2 ms     1 ms  2604:XX8X:f000:a111::86
3     2 ms     1 ms     2 ms  2604:XX8X:f010:207::1
4     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  2604:XX8X:f010:149::2
5     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  2604:XX8X:f010:190::1
6     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  2604:4XX:ffff:f3f6::1
7   121 ms   121 ms   121 ms  2001:450:2001:1000:0:67:1716:8158
8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
9     *      219 ms   220 ms  lo-0-v6.ear2.Frankfurt1.Level3.net [2001:1900:2::3:111]
10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
...
99     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

**www.avis.ad.jp**

```
Tracing route to www.avis.ad.jp [2406:8000:101:c020::2c]
over a maximum of 99 hops:

1     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  2604:XX8X:c98e:6f11:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX
2     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  2604:XX8X:f000:a111::86
3     2 ms    13 ms     2 ms  2604:XX8X:f010:207::1
4     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  2604:XX8X:f010:149::2
5     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  2604:XX8X:f010:190::1
6     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  2604:4XX:ffff:f3f6::1
7   121 ms   121 ms   121 ms  2001:450:2001:1000:0:67:1716:8158
8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
9   141 ms   140 ms   140 ms  lo-0-v6.ear1.Washington12.Level3.net [2001:1900::3:187]
10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
...
99     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

However, if I access a level3 page, it works! (Tested through Firefox)

**ipv6.test.level3.com**

```
Tracing route to ipv6.test.level3.com [2001:1900:2018:3000::105]
over a maximum of 99 hops:

1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  2604:XX8X:c98e:6f11:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX
2     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  2604:XX8X:f000:a111::86
3     5 ms     2 ms     2 ms  2604:XX8X:f010:207::1
4     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  2604:XX8X:f010:149::2
5     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  2604:XX8X:f010:190::1
6     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  2604:4XX:ffff:f3f6::1
7   121 ms   120 ms   120 ms  2001:450:2001:1000:0:67:1716:8158
8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
9   161 ms   160 ms   162 ms  lo-0-v6.ear1.Denver1.Level3.net [2001:1900::3:154]
10   165 ms   161 ms   161 ms  fe0-0-956.public2.Broomfield1.Level3.net [2001:1900:4:2::fa]
11   161 ms   160 ms   161 ms  2001:1900:2018:f000:1:0:1:202
12   161 ms   161 ms   161 ms  ipv6.test.Level3.com [2001:1900:2018:3000::105]

Trace complete.
```

So, is there something I can do to fix it?

Or is it a problem in the Level3.net network?

(I know I can use IPv4 (in some cases), but I want to understand why IPv6 doesn't work)

Comment: You edited out the important information (whether you get public IPv6 addresses for your LAN, but judging from `XX04`, likely not), while leaving in potentially privacy compromising information (like the MAC address of your end device). Please edit the question, provide the initial XXs, and insert some XXs at the end (if you have to). If you indeed don't get a public IPv6 address, then the reason is that this address is not routable outside the Level3 network, and apparently they don't do NAT.

Comment: I've edited it. Is it right now?

Comment: Are all of your 30 locations using the same ISP? Testing from 30 different AWS zones isn't going to tell you much if they all start at the same provider's backbone... I see many different paths to these sites and very few of them involve Level3. (And what _is_ your ISP, at least in the three tests that you've shown? Editing out such information is _really_ counter-productive.)

Answer (score 0):

The prefix `2604:...` is a public routable IPv6 prefix, so it should work. Possibly the problem is with the packets traceroute uses.

Try accessing a public IPv6 (e.g. Google, currently `2a00:1450:4001:81d::2004`) directly, e.g. in your browser or via `curl 'http://[2a00:1450:4001:81d::2004]/'. If that works, than your IPv6 connectivity works, and something between the Level 3 network and the other networks filters whatever packets your traceroute are using (there are different defaults for differents OS, you didn't tell us your OS).

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clearer. It also doesn't work from browser. Of course, ipv6.test.level3.com can be accessed, but most other sites can't.